# Tuple is converting float to string

Tags: python

I wrote a function to return the `lat, long` of an address from a ArcGIS server. The function is the following:

```
def get_lat_long(address):
    coordinates = geocode_address(address)
    lat = "{:.2f}".format(coordinates['y'])
    long = "{:.2f}".format(coordinates['x'])
    print(lat, long)  # prints: 42.34 -71.15
    return lat, long
```

As you can see, `lat, long` is a tuple of floats. However, when I call this function and print the type, it returns a string!

```
print(type(get_lat_long('<some address>')[0]))
# prints <class 'str'>
```

Why is this conversion happening? How can I keep `lat, long` as floats?

Comment: With `lat = "{:.2f}".format(coordinates['y'])` you are formatting your float coordinate as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When doing `lat = "{:.2f}".format(coordinates['y'])`, you're setting the value of `lat` to a formatted string with two decimal digits. (same for the variable `long`)

The float type of your variables isn't converted to a string by returning a tuple, but instead by formatting it this way.

If you only want to round to two decimal digits while retaining the type as float, use `round(number, 2)`, which will round the number to two decimal places.